# Error with libpam-systemd:amd64

Tags: 14.04

When I try and run sudo apt-get upgrade I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.7) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript systemd-logind, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is preventing me installing some things and obviously something has gone wrong. Does anyone know how to debug?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448961/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-247 here you can see how to debug post-installation scripts to find out the error

Comment: A reinstall of the libpam package is suggested here, but they dont say if it helped them in the end: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2281366

Answer (score 0):

try it

> kernel.kptr_restrict = 1

or (re)move the file

> /etc/sysctl.d/10-kernel-hardening.conf

Now the update process can complete :)

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head around this with one of our legacy systems today. This question was one of the first results when Googling around. So I'm leaving an answer here.

The issue is related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1325142

It was closed as a won't fix for the libpam-systemd package, but the long queue of comments contained some hints on how to fix it temporarly to overcome installation problems.

We went for commenting the service restarts `invoke-rc.d systemd-logind start || exit $?` in

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam-systemd\:amd64.postinst
```

and

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam-systemd\:amd64.prerm
```

Then running the `apt-get install` command with fix flag set:

```
apt-get -f install
```

And restored the previous versions of the installer scripts.

Surely, not the nicest 'solution', yet it got us going to install other packages.