# DPKG errors for hddtemp and glances when I run APT commands

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, juju, openstack

This is the output I am getting. What do I need to do?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lynx is already the newest version (2.8.9dev16-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libavahi-common-data:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up hddtemp (0.3-beta15-52) ...
Job for hddtemp.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl  status hddtemp.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript hddtemp, action "start" failed.
● hddtemp.service - LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/hddtemp; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2018-03-18 13:03:48 PDT; 9ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2648 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hddtemp start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/hddtemp.service
           ├─1428 plymouth --ping
           └─2651 plymouth --ping

Mar 18 12:58:48 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Mar 18 13:03:48 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: hddtemp.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 18 13:03:48 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Mar 18 13:03:48 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: hddtemp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 13:03:48 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: hddtemp.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
dpkg: error processing package hddtemp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up glances (2.10-2) ...
Job for glances.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl  status glances.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript glances, action "start" failed.
● glances.service - LSB: Starts and daemonize Glances server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/glances; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2018-03-18 13:08:49 PDT; 13ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2829 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/glances start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/glances.service
           ├─1429 plymouth --ping
           └─2832 plymouth --ping

Mar 18 13:03:49 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts and daemonize Glances server...
Mar 18 13:08:49 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: glances.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 18 13:08:49 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts and daemonize Glances server.
Mar 18 13:08:49 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: glances.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 13:08:49 hal9001-Inspiron-15-7000-Gaming systemd[1]: glances.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
dpkg: error processing package glances (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hddtemp
 glances
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Read the output - "lynx is already the newest version" so the problem is not with lynx ;)  "Errors were encountered while processing:
 hddtemp
 glances" Folowed by `See "systemctl  status hddtemp.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.` and `See "systemctl  status glances.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.` so post the output of those commands please.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: OK I see what you are saying now. I am new to linux more or less. It is already installed!

Comment: Open a terminal and run `journalctl -xe` as well as the 2 systemctl commands. Copy paste the output into your question or pastebin them if you can not edit your question. Use the code blocks around the text - the little "{}" icon at the top when you edit or post your question.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug report here.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hddtemp/+bug/1721585

but based on

[Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 247](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448961/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-247)

try this answer but try  with appropriate package instead of `gconf2`

[Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 247](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448961/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-247/449022#449022)