# "Unknown DAV provider: svn" when starting up Apache web server with Subversion server after reinstall

Tags: apt, 20.04, apache2, svn, webdav

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 PC that I am setting up as a Subversion server with Apache 2.4 web server to allow me to use the Ankh client plug-in with Visual Studio on a Windows 10 PC.

How do I fix the `Unknown DAV provider: svn` error reported by the Apache2 web server when I do a restart? I think it may be connected to an error I see, `dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-svn`, when doing a `sudo apt reinstall subversion`.

I originally had both Apache and Subversion installed and after making configuration file changes, it was working fine.

I then uninstalled and cleaned up both in order to redo the installation, documenting my procedure. I'm a bit hazy on the details however the basics were to:

- use `sudo apt remove apache2` and `sudo apt remove subversion`
- remove some remaining directories such as `/etc/apache2`

The reinstall has not gone well. For some reason installation seems to have been partial as if the `apt install` command was finding components and assuming other components also already existed when they did not. In some cases using `apt reinstall` has fixed issues and in other cases I built configuration files by hand.

I am now at the point where Apache web server is working and serving pages. Subversion is also working from the command line in Ubuntu.

I am now having a problem with the DAV component of Apache for the Subversion interface not working.

I am seeing an error when I attempt to enable the several `dav` related modules.

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2$ sudo a2enmod dav dav_fs dav_svn
Enabling module dav.
Considering dependency dav for dav_fs:
Module dav already enabled
Enabling module dav_fs.
Considering dependency dav for dav_svn:
Module dav already enabled
Enabling module dav_svn.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-12-13 15:21:50 EST; 13s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 74845 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 apachectl[74858]: [Sun Dec 13 15:21:50.461280 2020] [so:warn] [pid 74858] AH01574: module dav_fs_module is already loaded, skipping
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 apachectl[74858]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf:
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 apachectl[74858]: Unknown DAV provider: svn
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 apachectl[74845]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 apachectl[74845]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 13 15:21:50 rick-MS-7B98 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

When I attempt to do a `reinstall` of Subversion, I see a `dpkg: error processing package labapache2-mod-svn`

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ sudo ap reinstall subversion
sudo: ap: command not found
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ sudo apt reinstall subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/824 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 196796 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../subversion_1.13.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking subversion (1.13.0-3) over (1.13.0-3) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-svn (--configure):
 installed libapache2-mod-svn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up subversion (1.13.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-svn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I check the status of Subversion:

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ svn --version
svn, version 1.13.0 (r1867053)
   compiled Mar 24 2020, 12:33:36 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2019 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.9 (compiled with 1.3.9)
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Gnome Keyring
* GPG-Agent
* KWallet (KDE)
```

When I check to find out what uses `libapache2-mod-svn`, I get the following.

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ dpkg -S libapache2-mod-svn
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/examples/svnindex.css
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/INSTALL.authz.gz
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/README.Debian
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/changelog.Debian.gz
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/examples/svnindex.xsl
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libapache2-mod-svn
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/copyright
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/examples
libapache2-mod-svn: /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-svn/NEWS.Debian.gz
```

Comment: The Apache error message told you that you have a "*Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf*", specifically "*Unknown DAV provider: svn*." See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152437 for one possible solution.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for the comment. I think this is one of the articles and postings that I found while trying to research this problem however I wasn't sure as to whether it would apply. This post and others mention the `LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so` directive but I'm not sure where to put it.  I have an `httpd.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` but not linked to into `mods-enabled`. Perhaps I should add this to `mods-enabled/dav_svn.load`?

Comment: @user535733 Well how about that, I added the directive `LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so` to the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.load` and when I restart Apache, I don't see an error. I can now use the browser to look at my Subversion repository. If I do an edit to comment out the directive and restart Apache, I see the error. If you want to post an answer along these lines, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @user535733 by the way, any ideas as to the `dpkg: error processing package labapache2-mod-svn` error when doing the reinstall of Subversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of investigating setting up a Subversion repository with access via the Apache web server, I wanted to remove both Subversion and Apache2 then do the installation all over again.

When doing the installation a second time, it appears that the install resulted in some missing files and components, in particular `/etc/apache2/` files and directories such as `mods-enabled`. The several `dav` files (`dav_fs.conf`, `dav_fs.load`, `dav.load`, `dav_svn.conf`, and `dav_svn.load`) were also missing. However after redoing the `apt` command with the `reinstall` option, the files were recreated. in `mods-available` but the symbolic links in `mods-enabled` were not created for the `dav` files.

I was able to correct Apache2 server start up errors by looking at the status with the command `systemctl status apache2.service` and by looking at the Apache2 server logs in `/var/log/apache2` and searching the internet for the error messages.

With this error, several articles mentioned adding the directive `LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so` to the file `httpd2.conf` however in my Apache server there is a file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which appears to be the starting point for configuration parameters and during processing of this file, other files located in sub-directories per these comments from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
```

The additional configuration files are loaded with `IncludeOptional` directives in `apache2.conf`.

Based on the suggestion of @user535733, who pointed to [Unix & Linux StackExchange: Unknown DAV provider: svn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102740/unknown-dav-provider-svn/152437#152437), I decided to try the `LoadModule` directive by recreating the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.load` with the following:

```
# Depends: dav
LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

then doing the symbolic link into the directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`.

This worked once I also created the symbolic links for the other DAV related files (`dav_fs.conf`, `dav_fs.load`, and `dav.load`).

**sudo apt upgrade errors**

I thought that I had everything fixed however a few days later I tried to run `sudo apt upgrade` after running `sudo apt update` and the following errors were displayed:

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-svn (--configure):
 installed libapache2-mod-svn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-svn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried a couple of things to clear this error before finally able to do so.

I tried `sudo apt reinstall libapache2-mod-svn` which gave me a similar error.

I tried `sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-svn` which worked and I was able to do the `sudo apt upgrade` without an error however the module was now removed.

I tried `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn` which gave me a similar error.

I then tried several commands suggested in an article about this type of error: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` with the following errors:

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-svn (--configure):
 installed libapache2-mod-svn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-svn
rick@rick-MS-7B98:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-svn (--configure):
 installed libapache2-mod-svn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-svn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to correct these errors by using the `sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-svn` then doing `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` and then `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-svn` and it failed with similar error messages.

Finally I used a series of commands to remove (`sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-svn`), purge (`sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-svn`), and then install (`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn`) and that seemed to work fine with no errors. I then had to modify the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` file again and I was able to access my Subversion repository through `http://192.168.0.4/svn`.

```
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapache2-mod-svn
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 452 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 196824 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
apache2_invoke authz_svn prerm: No action required
apache2_invoke dav_svn prerm: No action required
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapache2-mod-svn*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 196812 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
apache2_invoke authz_svn postrm: No action required
apache2_invoke postrm: Purging state for dav_svn
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  db5.3-util
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-svn
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/87.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 452 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-svn.
(Reading database ... 196809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-svn_1.13.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-svn (1.13.0-3) ...
apache2_invoke: Enable module authz_svn
apache2_invoke dav_svn: already enabled
rick@rick-MS-7B98:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: This posting has a similar problem and answers posted in response mention doing the `purge` however there are other suggestions as well that may be effective in resolving this issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/448961/subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-247-for