# Bad uninstall of avg2013flx still causing prob (cont of my last issue)

Tags: uninstall, snap, tar, snap-store

The issue from my last post is still not solved and has rendered the Snap Store useless. I am getting an error that looks like this while uninstalling the Steam Installer.

```
"Unable to remove 'Steam Installer':
Error while installing package: installed avg2013flx package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"
```

Once again: how do I remove any mention of `avg2013flx` from my system? I made a bad tar install and attempted to manually remove every file that had the characters avg in it. Unfortunately it seems I did a poor job since I'm still getting errors like this.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, so the issue was resolved about 7 years ago (WOOOHOOO OLD FORUMS) and was centered in /var/lib/dpkg/info. Set that as the primary directory and run

```
ls |grep (whatever package is causing problems)
```

This lists incomplete items that is messing with your system.
Now remove these with

```
rm X && rm Y && rm Z && etc etc...
```

Many, many thanks to [these guys](https://askubuntu.com/a/449022/1550792)

Comment: Answer looks non-reproducible for me.

Comment: BTW you don't need to `grep` the output of `ls` - you can just put `ls whatever-package*` - result will likely be more readable like that. I would run `rm` on one file at a time rather than in a chain of commands - typing isn't saved here and there might be an error that holds things up. You'll also need `sudo` to `rm` files in this directory. Also future readers please note that this isn't a proper method - one should run `sudo dpkg --purge whatever-package` and only resort to deleting files manually if everything else has failed - you can cause further issues by doing that

Comment: The original issue wasn't solvable by dpkg. It was an incomplete tar install that just wouldn't go away

Comment: @N0rbert Did you type this literally? I used X, Y, and Z to describe whatever package is giving you trouble. I have done this twice now for bad installs so it should work.

Comment: well software installed from source usually only makes entries in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` if one uses `checkinstall` to make a deb package at install time, in which case there is no ordinary reason why purging with `dpkg` would not work. Even if this procedure was the only thing that worked in your case, I left the comment for other readers who could benefit from trying a more standard approach first.

Comment: That's good of you. I don't know, maybe I got a bad version, maybe I'll just avoid tar files like the plague since I don't understand them. But for anyone diving deep into the archives of the internet to find this, please do lots and lots of reading before installing anything. Especially tars.